# why to pass a function as an argument in javascript? what's the point?

Tags: javascript, function

i am confused why we need to do a such thing ?

for example :

```
function firstFunction ( x , secondFunction){
    var z = x*x ;
    y = secondFunction(z);
    return y;
}
```

i'm coming from java and in java there is no need to pass an function as an argument instead we use this function in the body of the first function everywhere is need ... and even the worse is why as a argument we should define a function ?
like this :

```
function firstFunction (x , secondFunction(){
    // some computation 
       return z;
};){
    retrun x
}
```

it is very hard to understand and when i first saw something like this i was just wondering how can it be legal to do this... am i wrong in somehow ?

Comment: In Java 8 you _can_ pass a function (aka lambda)

Comment: This is an example of currying

Comment: Passing functions as arguments is a fundamental concept in functional programming and JavaScript was the first mainstream programming language to incorporate this concept. Languages like C#, C++, and VB.NET scrambled to follow suit, and Java too has finally come around. [Execution in the Kingdom of Nouns](http://steve-yegge.blogspot.jp/2006/03/execution-in-kingdom-of-nouns.html)

Comment: (@JLRishe I'd argue it was the "first mainstream language" to do this; passing function pointers in C is the same thing, and Lisp used to be mainstream.)

Comment: @DaveNewton passing a function pointer in C isn't the same as passing a function object and all of its associated state

Comment: @Alnitak Agreed. But on the conceptual level, passing functions around is nothing new, and closures aren't either. It's the closures that give functions that state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why to pass a function as an argument in javascript? what's the point?

One possible situation coming to my mind is, you can give control to the devs to alter the end result based on their expectation. This is how lot of core functions are working in javascript.

For example:

```
function addItWithFive(x) { return x + 5 };
function addItWithTen(x) { return x + 10 };

function firstFunction ( x , secondFunction){
    var z = x*x ;
    y = secondFunction(z);
    return y;
}

//one dev will call it like below
var res = firstFunction(5, addItWithFive); //30

//Another one dev will call it like below
var res = firstFunction(5, addItWithTen); //35
```

Answer (score 3):

(Too long for a reasonable comment.)

You don't pass functions in Java because you *can't* (until Java 8).

Instead you pass implementations of interfaces, like a comparator. In JavaScript you do the same thing with the `sort` method, but pass only the comparison function–you don't need the class, just the thing that actually does the work.

You also use function references for callbacks, like for async calls or event handlers: again, precisely as in Java, but in Java you have to pass a class that can be instantiated, or an instance of an existing class.